# getAbsolutePath() displays nothing?

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to display the path of the file by calling getAbsolutePath(), but the Application

displays nothing.

Java Code:

```
public void createExternalStorageDirectory() {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", " Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of 'fileName'?

Comment: String fileName = "DemoFile.jpg";

Comment: Print out the content of getExternalFilesDir(null). Does the toast come upp?

Comment: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+getExternalFilesDir(null), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  displays nothing

Comment: I mean, does the atleast the toast display? or is the toast empty? Did you use the right external file permissions?

Comment: i have not used any permissions in the manifest file, should I?

Comment: now, it works, i dont know that i had to add permission to the manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the External File permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And try using getApplicationContext() intead of getBaseContext()

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of getExternalFilesDir(null)

Comment: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); also displays nothing

Comment: It's still not clear what you see, does the toast show-up but empty? Or the toast itself is not showing?